# SML: Filtering list non-recursively

Tags: list, filter, sml

I'm trying to filter a list non-recursively but I'm not sure how to go about going it.
For a simple example, say I have a list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] and I want to filter it so it returns a list of numbers greater than 3, ie [4, 5, 6, 7].

I can do it recursively no problem but I'm stuck here. Unfortunately, I'm new to sml and the best I can think of is using map but I don't think map was made for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right: `map` wasn't made for this - the list produced by `map` will always have the same size as the list given to `map`.

`List.filter` however *was* made for this. If you call `List.filter` with a function as an argument that returns true if a number is greater than 3, it will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try it using `foldr`, not `map`.